# Result not correct when using if, left and search in excel

Tags: excel, string, search

I am trying to extract the text to the right of a character pattern of form `-201*-*-` in excel (I also tried using Access, but the issue persists).

For example, in the text:

> EP-005-FI6-2012-1-124-000000-1

I want to extract the number `124`; the following formula works:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(C1,SEARCH("-201*-*-",C1)+1),3)
```

`124`

However, when i apply the exact same formula to extract`169` from the text below:

> NAATS-MG-D6-2017-1-169-070000-1

The formula returns a completely different result:

`=LEFT(RIGHT(C540495,SEARCH("-201*-*-",C540495)+1),3)`

```
-16
```

The pattern is the same, but the results is completely differnt.

My dataset is too big to go row by row fixing the issue...
Seems to be a simple problem, but i can't get this working...

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RIGHT()` is wrong.  Use:

```
=LEFT(MID(C1,SEARCH("-201?-?-",C1)+8,9999),3)
```